# How do I compile a driver for Windows Vista in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, driver, wdk

I want my driver to be supported by Windows Vista. I am using Visual Studio 2015 for development. I have downloaded and installed WDK 10 which supports my driver down to Windows 7. According to [this site](http://www.windrvr.com/2015/05/11/wdk-installation-tips/) I need WDK 8 for my driver to be compatible with Windows Vista. After I installed the WDK 8 i cannot set it in Visual Studio.

What is the proper way to integrate WDK 8 into Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WDK 8 can be used till Visual Studio 2012, after that it is not officially supported. Check link

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

It clearly says that:

We provide Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8 to give you time to migrate to WDK 8.1 Update and Visual Studio 2013. Microsoft does not support WDK 8 and will make no further updates to this kit. We recommend that you use the latest versions of the WDK and Visual Studio to build drivers for Windows.

Important: You must install Visual Studio Professional 2012 or Visual Studio Ultimate before you install WDK 8.

So for using WDK 8 and driver for Vista you need Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thank you for your research. It is just ridiculous that an SDK depends on a specific version of an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WDK 7 to produce drivers compatible with Vista. If you wish to "integrate" it to Visual Studio, look at VisualDDK (http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/), however, it probably does not officially support Visual Studio 2015.

Another way of making drivers compatible with Vista is to compile your driver with the current WDK (WDK 10) and have a closer look why it does not work under Vista. The incompatibility is usually caused by missing imports which can be partially solved by disabling various checks in your driver project (e.g. security check). By this approach, you can even be compatible with XP (at least, it worked for me with WDK 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get Windows Driver Kit 7 or 8. Looks like the WDK support for Vista was dropped in 8.1. If you want to build drivers for Windows 7 and up then WDK 10 should work.

Here's the link to WDK 7.1.0:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800